# Trouble linking models together in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 3 models/tables as described

**`holding`**

An individual financial holding for a portfolio at a point in time. The fields here are `id`, `date`, `sedol_id`, `value`

---

**`sedol`**

A table with sedol-specific data.

---

**`asset`**

More general data about an asset. Several sedols can refer to the same asset, but a sedol only refers to one asset.

Here is an overview of the linking:

[image: tables]

I'm struggling to associate the models in the Cake. Which model `hasOne`, `hasMany` or `belongsTo` the other. I have tried many combinations but either get a memory exhausted error (infinate loop?) or an SQL error where the joining is not done correctly.

Here's an example in case my question isn't clear.

Let's say there's a `holding` records which is shares in Vodafone PLC. this might appear in the holdings table like

```
     id   | sedol  |   date     | value
   ---------------------------------------
   123456 | 16GWD5 | 2013-09-15 | 15456.25
```

Now this holding's sedol refers to the Sedol table which has share-specific info. Among this info in the SEDOL table is an ips_asset_id which refers to the company itself. E.g. Vodafone may have several different classes of shares (represented by sedols) but the fundementals of the company equity would be in the ips_assets table.

---

EDIT: OK I think I have solved the joins but when I query the database to find all the sedols it tries to retreive every holding, when all I want to do is get the data from the holdings table. Any ideas?

Comment: Only use hasMany if there is a one to many relationship.  Can a holding have more than one sedol?  Can a sedol have more than one asset?  If yes, then use hasMany.  If this is true though, you'll have to move which table your foreign key is located on.  The way your tables are designed, they are set up for a belongsTo association, that is holdings belongsTo sedols, and sedols belongsTo ips_assets.  More on cake relationships at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: I tried doing holdings belongsTo Sedols & Sedols belongsTo ips_assets. And Sedols hasMany Holdings & ips_assets hasOne Sedol but I get infinite loop

Comment: Infinite loops do not normally happen just by making model relationship associations (though I suppose anything is possible).  I'd try selectively commenting out code to narrow down where exactly the infinite loop is happening.

Comment: Solved (I think). The reason it hung was that it was recursively finding all holdings (as they are linked to sedols) of which there are thousands of records. This caused memory limit to be hit. Setting `recursive => 0` seems to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example:

- `Holding belongsTo Sedol`
- `Sedol belongsTo IpsAsset`

However, I don’t know enough about your models to know whether the relationships the other way are would be a `hasOne` or `hasMany`.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was it. I thought that was wrong initially due to exhausted memory limits but solved as in comments above

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: Although I am still getting memory limit exhausted now when I try to output the result in the view. The query summary at at the bottom show 1 query which returns 316 rows. That is not enough to cause a memory problem. Why is this happening?

Comment: I wouldn’t know off-hand. What does your **error.log** in **app/tmp/logs** say?